# Switch statement in Java displays weird output after removing "break;"

Tags: java, switch-statement

I'have created this code but the output of it is weird.. Maybe cause I'm new at Java. I expect from this code the output `2 1 0` but when I remove the `break` statement after all the `case` statements this weird output displays: `2 1 2 0 1 2`

Can someone please explain why this happens? This is my code:

```
public class Sem2 {
    final static short x = 2;

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        for (int z=0; z < 3; z++) 
        {
            switch (z) 
            {
                case x: System.out.print("0 ");
                case x-1: System.out.print("1 ");
                case x-2: System.out.print("2 ");
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you expecting after you removed the `break`s ?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html

Comment: @MohammedAoufZOUAG 2 1 0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without break statement it will continue to execute other statements too. by using break it exit from switch case after matched case.

Answer (score 2):

The keyword `break` is needed to break out of each case of the switch statement.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html

> ...Each break statement terminates the enclosing switch statement.
>   Control flow continues with the first statement following the switch
>   block. The break statements are necessary because without them,
>   statements in switch blocks fall through: All statements after the
>   matching case label are executed in sequence, regardless of the
>   expression of subsequent case labels, until a break statement is
>   encountered